# Gitlab-ci.yml Pipeline failed

Tags: gitlab-ci, cicd, gitlab-ci.yml

Could you please help me with what could be the issue with the `gitlab-ci.yml` file here? I have this code:

```yaml
variables:
  SECURE_ANALYZERS_PREFIX: "$CI_TEMPLATE_REGISTRY_HOST/security-products"
  SAST_IMAGE_SUFFIX: ''
  SAST_EXCLUDED_ANALYZERS: ''
  SAST_EXCLUDED_PATHS: spec, test, tests, tmp
  SCAN_KUBERNETES_MANIFESTS: 'false'

stages:
  - test
  - process-js
  - process-php

phpcs-security-audit-sast:
  image: registry.gitlab.com/security-products/sast/phpcs-security-audit:2
  stage: test
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - gl-sast-report.json
  rules:
  - if: "$SAST_DISABLED == 'true' || $SAST_DISABLED == '1'"
    when: never
  - if: "$SAST_EXCLUDED_ANALYZERS =~ /phpcs-security-audit/"
    when: never
  - if: "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH"
    exists:
    - "**/*.php"
  variables:
    SEARCH_MAX_DEPTH: 4
    SAST_ANALYZER_IMAGE_TAG: 4
    SAST_ANALYZER_IMAGE: "$SECURE_ANALYZERS_PREFIX/phpcs-security-audit:$SAST_ANALYZER_IMAGE_TAG"      
  script:
    - /analyzer run

nodejs-scan-sast:
  stage: test
  artifacts:
    reports:
      sast:
      - gl-sast-report.json
  rules:
  - if: "$SAST_DISABLED == 'true' || $SAST_DISABLED == '1'"
    when: never
  - if: "$SAST_EXCLUDED_ANALYZERS =~ /nodejs-scan/"
    when: never
  - if: "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH"
    exists:
    - "**/package.json"
  variables:
    SEARCH_MAX_DEPTH: 4
    SAST_ANALYZER_IMAGE_TAG: 4
    SAST_ANALYZER_IMAGE: "$SECURE_ANALYZERS_PREFIX/nodejs-scan:$SAST_ANALYZER_IMAGE_TAG"
  script:
  - "/analyzer run"

zpracovani-json-phpcs:
  image: cylab/php74
  stage: process-php
  needs:
    - job: phpcs-security-audit-sast
  script:
    - php sast-vuln-checker.php gl-sast-report.json $CI_PROJECT_NAME

zpracovani-json-nodejs:
  image: cylab/php74
  stage: process-php
  needs:
    - job: nodejs-scan-sast
  script:
    - php sast-vuln-checker.php gl-sast-report.json $CI_PROJECT_NAME
```

But it still fails with the error:

> Unable to create pipeline
> 'zpracovani-json-nodejs' job needs 'nodejs-scan-sast' job, but 'nodejs-scan-sast' is not in any previous stage

I would need to perform `SAST` scanning for `PHP` and `JS` within the CI/CD.

Comment: You have a set of rules configured for the job nodejs-scan-sast. The job may not get executed based on the outcome of the rules. If it is not getting executed because of the rules, your subsequent job will not be able to find it and results in this error.